# Taking all the blood of a dozen humans and putting it into acid – could I create a wolf?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design

My story includes an evil mage that can manipulate everything that comes into contact with acid on a molecular level. This means if something touches acid there will be the normal chemical reaction going on and afterwards the mage can magically extract all molecules that are not acid from this reaction and rearrange the molecules in whatever way he wants.

If I were to collect **the blood of a dozen virgins** (read: [roughly average european humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_body_weight) with a height of ~1,70 metres and a weight of ~70 kg) and toss all of it **into a big pool of stomach acid** my mage could use all the products of the chemical reaction to create a creature for his evil army, for example [**a wolf**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_wolf).

**How close to a wolf can I get if my mage were to use all the molecules in the pool that are not stomach acid to create this creature?**

Even when the goal is to come as close to a normal living wolf as possible it’s most important to create something that **looks** like a big wolf to a frightened villager in a medieval fantasy setting involving a lot of magic. Therefore it doesn’t have to be alive and can miss or have other characteristics as well so long as the appearance still resembles a wolf.

What I am thinking about: the products from this reaction may be not sufficient to create a creature, but I don’t know what would be missing or how to use excess products as all products need to be used in the process. For example would this creature have none or a lot of the following:

- fur?
- teeth?
- muscles?
- eyes?
- bones?
- a brain?

This question is similar to another one I asked before ([Using only molecules found in humans: How close can I get to creating a wolf?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/74130/using-only-molecules-found-in-humans-how-close-can-i-get-to-creating-a-wolf)), but this time **I don’t ask about transforming the whole human body into a werewolf**. Instead **I want to build a wolf only from digested blood** (meaning the blood has to have reacted with the stomach acid before being used).

Comment: I have the feeling it would be a pretty small and very floppy wolf...

Comment: Why does the blood have to go into acid? Acid breaks down the molecules and you'd have to do more work to "assemble" the wolf.

Comment: @AndreiROM My mage likes throwing stuff into acid

Comment: why do you limit yourself to blood? e.g. to make bones you need lot of calcium... you could get it from the women's bones...

Comment: @L.Dutch Why not? I want to get close to something resembling a wolf, it doesn't necessarily need to be a complete normal wolf. In the Sandbox kingledion mentioned the same problem - and that you could use the iron from the blood to make iron-teeth as an example. If I were using the whole body again this would be an obvious duplicate to the existing question. I want to explore ways to utilize blood in a magical setting without goind "sacrifice blood and summon a demon from another dimension"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using only molecules found in humans: How close can I get to creating a wolf?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/74130/using-only-molecules-found-in-humans-how-close-can-i-get-to-creating-a-wolf)

Comment: DNA _is_ an acid. Your mage might get some protein and minerals, but then would have to put them together from scratch. Might be easier to start with plant protein or something

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are doing it at the molecular level there isn't a lot of difference between wolf and human.  Carbon, hydrogen, oxygen, nitrogen, phosphorus, magnesium calcium form the big bulk.  AFter that there are traces of lots of other things.

Bones are a mix of MgCO3 and CaCO3
Hair is a protein keratin -- same as fingernails and much of skin.

Could you do it with just blood?  Would take a lot of it.  Blood doesn't have a lot of P, Mg, Ca.  But if you throw intact virgins into it, then you should be able to get roughly a pound of wolf for each pound of human.

You need to justify why virgins work better than cows however. Much easier to get along with the neighbors if you buy their old cows instead of just taking their daughters.