# How could an animal grow hair overnight?

Tags: biology, fauna, genetics, genetic-engineering

I am trying to create scientifically accurate werewolves. Of course, werewolves are not really possible, but I am trying to make mine as believable as possible. How could they quickly grow hair/fur in a short time when they change?

As for when it is over, their hair/fur sheds very fast.

Comment: It's very close to the [Anatomically-correct werewolf](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26001/anatomically-correct-werewolves) question. Is there any answer that helps you there?

Comment: @Tortliena no, but thanks anyway.

Comment: What prevents it from meeting your needs? If you don't give any element that makes this question different, your question might get closed as a duplicate of the one I linked :/.

Comment: @Tortliena this one goes about hair growth, while the one you provided was about the body of a werewolf.

Comment: Including rapid hair growth and anatomically-correct werewolves. You just asked a more specific question :).

Answer (score 1):

## They grow hair over a month.

It's not possible to grow hair that fast. But, let us look to bamboo and grasses, which can get very tall very quickly. How do they manage it? [By cheating](https://www.ambientbp.com/blog/the-incredible-bamboo-plant)

The werewolves, like bamboo, stockpile cells over the month. Then, when they transform, the cells are hydrated and can pop out very quickly. They can grow at 1.5 inches an hour, and pop out very quickly.

This means if they transform too much they'll run out of hair.

Answer (score 0):

**Glue, and loose hair.**

[image: beavis and butthead with beards]

[source](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/when-i-see-men-who-cant-grow-a-beard-but-try-anyway--383228249514529903/)

Beavis and Butthead had to relocate hair from their heads to make their beards.  Your werewolves have a modicum of hair at all times.  They are very careful to keep shed hair clean and dry.  Then when needed, they roll in sticky stuff (which they also have on hand) and then apply the reserve fur.  Presto: Beards!  Or Fur!  Both!

You could have the sticky stuff be spray-on if you wanted.

I was sure I would find an image of one of those hairless cats, with a bunch of spare hair that the owners had applied.  I understand they are naturally sticky, those cats. But no luck.  Anyone who can find such an image please add it.  Anyone who has such a cat, please produce such an image and add it.